# prevent ctrl-o from jumping to another file

Tags: vim

I use ctrl-o and ctrl-i habitually to go back to old locations, and return to newer locations.  If ctrl-o changes files, I can still ctrl-I to return, but I can no longer undo recent edits from before the ctrl-o.  Is there a setting that will prevent changing files when attempting ctrl-o?

**One main usage context**

I use the following key mapping to format a paragraph:

```
nmap Z {gq}<C-O><C-O>
```

It uses `ctrl-o` to position the cursor where it was before reformatting.

If the very first line in the file is non-blank, and the cusor is resting somewhere in the middle of that paragraph, then it seems that `{` fails, and the double `<C-O>` causes to cursor to jump too far back in the jump list, sometimes to a different file.

Similar problems occur if the last line in the file is non-blank.

The normal mode command `gqip` is not sufficient for this job because it does not put the cursor back where it was.  Furthermore, `ctrl-o` will not put the cursor back after `gqip`.

A non-ideal work-around might be to set a mark to return to, e.g., `mq`, and hope that I don't clobber a pre-existing mark `q`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of preventing `Ctrl-O` from changing a file (which would make `Ctrl-O` a lot less useful), let's make Vim remember undo history for all opened buffers. Put the following in your vimrc:

```
set hidden
```

After that, you'll be able to undo/redo changes after changing a file.

And, even more than that, Vim can remember all undo history even after you close it and open again! (provided that the file was not changed by another program while vim was closed). This is called "Persistent undo", and can be activated as follows:

```
set undofile
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'll test-drive the `hidden` option, and see if it's necessary to use the `undofile` options.  Thanks!

Comment: It has been a while, but I keep running into the problem of jumping into a different file and losing my undo's in the old file.  Setting the hidden option, but it keeping the buffer loaded interferes with other things.  I realize that there is an [enhanced vim jump plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695), but was wondering if there is a way to achieve the equivalent of in-file ctrl-o in the vimrc, i.e., without managing another plugin.